# porque al enviar un archivo base64 me da un error 414

Tags: laravel, post

Estoy enviando un archivo base64 por POST, pero me arroja un error que este es muy largo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El Base64 que veo que estás enviando en esa imagen está mal, debería empezar así:

```
'data:{FORMATO};base64,'
```

Donde FORMATO puede ser por ejemplo en imagen png: image/png.

Deberías revisar el archivo cuando lo estas creando y verificar que lo contenga.

Comment: es un pdf, que pase a base64, donde iría el codigo ? en {formato}

Comment: Debería de verse algo así `data:application/pdf;base64,DATA` data sería la data del pdf.